# Change values of rows in a column given a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

Im making a sript to update `NA` values of rows in a column.
The problem is that I need to update the values with a value that exist in the column.
For example:

I have the next DataFrame:

```
VehicleID  1    English   4WAS(FRONT)
1          1    Release   Model 
2          2    <NA>      <NA>            
3          3    <NA>      <NA>            
4          4    <NA>      <NA>
5          5    FORD      h2
6          6    <NA>      <NA>
7          7    MAZDA      h3
8          8    <NA>      h3
9          9    <NA>      h3
```

I want to update the NA rows of the column 3 when a brand name appears
The expected output is:

```
VehicleID  1    English   4WAS(FRONT)
1          1    Release   Model 
2          2    <NA>      <NA>            
3          3    <NA>      <NA>            
4          4    <NA>      <NA>
5          5    FORD      h2
6          6    FORD      <NA>
7          7    MAZDA     h3
7          7    MAZDA     h3
8          8    MAZDA     h3
9          9    MAZDA     h3
```

How I can do that with every `NA` row in the column?

Comment: Try with `df1 %>% fill(English)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that solved the problem for now.